# PHP Curl sometimes gets a 404 error when loading images but it works with file_get_contents() why is that?

Tags: php, curl, header

Sometimes I get a 404 error when trying to access a webpage via curl but if I use file_get_contents to access the exact same URL it works, any idea why it's like that?

Here is an example:
My curl settings:

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->UserAgent);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->CookieFile);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->CookieFile);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

The request header with my firefox webbrowser:

```
GET /image.png HTTP/1.1
Host: ssl.website.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: some cookie info
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2012 13:38:43 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Server: '; DROP TABLE servertypes; --
```

Comment: Hi, Bobby Tables `Server: '; DROP TABLE servertypes; --`

Comment: I guess you'll have to ask the guys at http://reddit.com why they 404 your requests.

Comment: That is not the only site, I sometimes get 404s on some images from different sites. The strange thing is why it works with file_get_contents()

Comment: Define "sometimes". Do you mean that _some_ URLs give 404 with Curl but work with `file_get_contents`, or that _the same_ URL _sometimes_ works and sometimes gives 404?

Comment: @lanzz I wonder if they've ever caught some little script kiddy out with that and eaten their database. One can only hope...

Comment: _"any idea why it's like that?"_ - No, and it's up to you to find out. We can't debug your code nor your URL's. Put a proxy in between or capture network traffic and take a look at the headers that both `CURL` and `file_get_contents()` send, then compare and try to make them equal.

Comment: some urls give the 404, the strange thing is if I open a new curl handle it works all of a sudden. I can use the old curl handle to open as many web urls as I want and it works but with the image it fails.